# Fetch data using phpquery

Tags: php, phpquery

i have to fetch  data from web page using phpquery and i have already used a example

this following is the code...

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/phpQuery.php");
phpQuery::browserGet('http://www.google.com/', 'success1');
function success1($browser) {
  $browser
    ->WebBrowser('success2')
    ->find('input[name=q]')
      ->val('search phrase')
      ->parents('form')
        ->submit();
}
function success2($browser) {
  print $browser;
}
```

and right now i have a new error that is

```
Warning: require_once(WebBrowser.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/TantraProjects/phpQuery/phpQuery.php on line 4922 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'WebBrowser.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/TantraProjects/phpQuery/phpQuery/:/var/www/TantraProjects/phpQuery/phpQuery/plugins/') in /var/www/TantraProjects/phpQuery/phpQuery.php on line 4922
```

i cant understand why this is shown , help me...

Answer (score 0):

most obviously you don't have phpQuery.php in the same directory as you script - mind you: On a Linux webhost filenames are case-sensitive.

Comment: No, i have the file phpQuery.php in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

It's an additional file that needs to be available for reading.

The [phpQuery WebBroswer](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/WebBrowser) is a plugin. Check that you have put that file (`WebBrowser.php`) into the location it gives you the error and that it's available to be read, e.g.

```
/var/www/TantraProjects/phpQuery/WebBroswer.php
```